# Prevent div containing CSS menu from wrapping without breaking menu dropdowns

Tags: css

I'm implementing a menu based on this one:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/01/19/Create-Vimeo-like-top-navigation.aspx

([Demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/vimeo_navigation/))

The menu uses a UL / LI structure and CSS for appropriate rendering.

The trouble is, if the browser is not wide enough, the main menu items wrap.

[image: Menu wrapping]

I have surrounded the menu in a DIV.

When I apply

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

to that DIV, mousing over a menu item causes scroll bars to appear around the DIV (presumably to accommodate the drop down menus).

How can I prevent the DIV from wrapping while retaining the drop-down menus?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a fixed width to the div tag, like such `width: 700px;`

Comment: The menu itself will be variable-width.  I guess I could go with `width:10000px;` or something but it feels like there must be a better way.

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap;`, but then you might have to put a hidden text in with the last rounding image on the right.

Comment: Normally, I would specify a width for the body, or the main container. If you do that, you can set the width of the div to `width:100%` instead.

Comment: `width:100%` does not work.  That just sets the width to however wide the screen currently is.

Comment: Are you using IE? I think the `white-space: nowrap;` doesn't work so well with IE. Regarding setting the `width:100%`, you would also have to define a width for the `body` tag, or if you have a main `div` container.

Comment: Yes, IE.  It has to work in major browsers :-)  Setting an unnecessarily wide width leads to a nasty scrollbar at the bottom of the browser.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want to define a width for your web application. I think it's a good practice for any web application to define the width either in the body tag or in a main container. How else would you have control over how your content is displayed?

Comment: Here's a link to some [browser display statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp), so you will know what resolution you can expect most users to have, and design accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is the one suggested in the comments in The Jonas Persson's answer. It's using `white-space: nowrap`. For this to work though, you'd have to be using `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left/right` to horizontally align the menu's elements.

I played around with your demo using chrome's web developer and made it work.

Just replace every `float: left` with `display: inline-block` Add `font-size: 0` to `ul#menu` and override it on `ul#menu li` with `font-size:12px` - that's the size your using. (Using `display: inline-block` adds some whitespace between the blocks. That `font-size` stuff takes care of it.).

Next ensure the inline blocks are vertically aligned with the top of the container - add `vertical-align: top` to the `li`'s.

Finally, add the `whitespace: no-wrap` to the div wrapping `ul#menu`. That's it.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to mention you had to add vertical-align top to the inline-blocks... It's all in the answer now.